# wdio-video-reporter error : videoRenderTimeout triggered, not all videos finished writing to disk before patching Allure

Tags: wdio

`
reporters: [
[video, {
saveAllVideos: true,       // If true, also saves videos for successful test cases
videoSlowdownMultiplier: 3, // Higher to get slower videos, lower for faster videos [Value 1-100]
videoRenderTimeout: 25,      // Max seconds to wait for a video to finish rendering
}],
['allure', {
outputDir: './*results*/allure-raw',
disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,
useCucumberStepReporter: true,
}],
],
This is my config wdio-video-reporter
And I have a problem here : [0-0] videoRenderTimeout triggered, not all videos finished writing to disk before patching Allure . Help me please :(
I have a problem here : [0-0] videoRenderTimeout triggered, not all videos finished writing to disk before patching Allure . Help me please